# Knockout: nesting doesn't recognize parent's model

Tags: knockout.js

I have something like this:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: tuts" class="tutorsTable">
(...) //here it sees my model
<!-- ko if: date.getTime() > (new Date().getTime() - 900000) -->
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="center">
            <a data-bind="attr: { href: 'https://mypage.com/videoconference/talk/' + peer + '/1/1/0'}, text: 'Start!'"></a>//this is being rendered as is
        </td>
    </tr>
<!-- /ko -->
</table>
```

Why it is rendering code inside the `if` statement as-is, and not executing `data-bind` attribute instead?

Comment: How are you initializing knockout? eg... ko.applybindings(...)

Comment: Yes, by doing `ko.applybindings()`. Also the rows in my table where `(...)` is, are rendering properly, `peer` property is being successfully rendered there.

Comment: Do each of the tuts have  date attribute that is not an observable?  If the date property is observable you need to use date().getTime()

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors? Could you create a jsfiddle which reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my date representation. It was being a plain string, what I needed to do is to initialize `new Date(date.replace(/(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2})/,'$3-$2-$1 $4:$5')).getTime()`

Comment: Definitely put that in a computed observable and not in your binding, if only for the sake of being able to unit-test it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<!-- ko if -->` inside `<tr>` tag

```
<table data-bind="foreach: tuts" class="tutorsTable">
    <tr>
    <!-- ko if: date.getTime() > (new Date().getTime() - 900000) -->
        <td colspan="2" class="center">
            <a data-bind="attr: { href: 'https://mypage.com/videoconference/talk/' + peer + '/1/1/0'}, text: 'Start!'"></a>//this is being rendered as is
        </td>
    <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Otherwise you will get

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find closing comment tag to match <!- ko...
```

exception.
Also you should use `date().getTime()` if your date is `observable`
[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SNyvk/)

Comment: Ok, but what if OP does not want to render the whole `tr` if the condition is not true?